Show that function has no global minima
Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $D \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be compact sets, and let $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Define the functions $g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $h : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$g(x) := \max\{\phi(x, y) \mid y \in D\}, \quad h(y) := \min\{\phi(x, y) \mid x \in C\}$
Show that $\max\{\min\{\phi(x, y) \mid x \in C\} \mid y \in D\} = \max\{h(y) \mid y \in D\} \leq \min\{g(x) \mid x \in C\}$.
My idea: Let $y_0 \in D$ be so that it maximizes $h$ and $x_0 \in C$ so that it minimizes $g$. Then maybe find some inequality using these variables however I haven't come up with one yet?
Thanks for any help!
Edit: Thanks for the answers. I have tried an example however I get a contradiction:
$\phi(x,y)=xy+y^2,C=D=[-1,1]$
Then $g(x)=\max\{x+1,1-x\}$ because the maximum is attained at $y=\pm1$ and $h(y)=\min\{y+y^2,-y+y^2\}$ because the minimum is attained at $x=\pm1$.
But then the minimum of $g$ in $x$ is $0$ and the maximum of $h$ in $y$ is $2$. I must have made some error! Could you tell me where?

It is $h(y) \leq \phi(x,y) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in C$ and $y \in D$ per definition of $h$ and $g$ as minimum and maximum. Therefore $\max\{h(y)|y\in D\} \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in C$ and thus $\max{\{h(y)|y\in D\}} \leq \min{\{g(x)|x \in C\}}$.

Let $(x_0,y_0)\in C\times D$ and observe that
$$\phi(x_0,y_0)\leq\max_{y\in D}\phi(x_0,y).$$
Consequently, taking a minimum over all $x_0$ on both sides (which we can do as $x_0\in C$ is arbitrary),
$$\min_{x\in C}\phi(x,y_0)\leq\min_{x\in C}\max_{y\in D}\phi(x,y).$$
As $y_0\in D$ is arbitrary, taking a maximum over all $y_0$ on both sides we get that
$$\max_{y\in D}\min_{x\in C}\phi(x,y)\leq\min_{x\in C}\max_{y\in D}\phi(x,y),$$
where the right hand side is the same as it was independent of $y_0$. This proves the inequality.
